# How to use the Word RepeatingSection ContentControl in a protected word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

List item

I am implementing a Word template for a form filling application using VSTO and c# in Visual Studio 2017 and wish to take advantage of Word repeating section content control. However, I am being prevented from programmatically applying this type of control after I have previously protected the document for form filling. It appears that unprotecting the document does not return the document to the same unprotected state in this context as prior to protecting it. Here is a stripped down demonstration program to highlight the problem:

In Visual Studio create a new Word 2013 and 2016 VSTO Template project, leaving the project to use an  unchanged default blank document template, add the following code to the ThisDocument partial class

```
private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Demonstrates an unexpected impact of protecting then subsequently unprotecting a document 
        AddTableDirect();
        DocProtect();
        DocUnprotect();
        AddTableRepeatingSection();
    }
    private void ThisDocument_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void DocProtect()
    {
        //Protects the active document restricting the operator to form filling
        object noReset = true;
        object password = System.String.Empty;
        object useIRM = false;
        object enforceStyleLock = false;
        this.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields,
            ref noReset, ref password, ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);
    }
    private void DocUnprotect()
    {
        // Unprotects the active document allowing programmatic manipulation
        object password = System.String.Empty;
        this.Unprotect(ref password);
    }
    private void AddTableDirect()
    {
        //Creates a one row table directly adding a single plain text content control
        Word.Range range = this.Sections[1].Range.Paragraphs[1].Range;
        Word.Table table = this.Tables.Add
            (range, 1, 1, Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord9TableBehavior, Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow);
        Word.ContentControl cc = this.ContentControls.Add
            (Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlText, table.Cell(1, 1).Range);
    }
    private void AddTableRepeatingSection()
    {
        //Programatically duplicates the table as a repeating section
        Word.Table table = this.Sections[1].Range.Tables[1];
        Word.Range rSRange = table.Range;
        Word.ContentControl rSCC = this.ContentControls.Add
            (Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRepeatingSection, rSRange);
        rSCC.RepeatingSectionItems[1].InsertItemAfter();
    }
```

If you build and run this code as is then a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` is generated with text: "This method or property is not available because the current selection partially covers a plain text content control" on the statement that adds the Repeating Section control in the `AddTableRepeatingSection()` method (the line before `InsertItemAfter`).

However if you comment out the `DocProtect()` and `DocUnprotect()` statements in `ThisDocument_StartUp` then this code runs successfully.

What do I need to change to enable me to protect and unprotect the document without generating this exception when programmatically applying the repeating section content control?

Comment: 1) Content controls are native to WORD and have nothing to do with Windows forms. 2) Do *NOT* use `this.Application.ActiveDocument` in a VSTO document-level customization. `this` does represent the VSTO document. If you want to work with the native object, rather than the VSTO object, then use `this.InnerObject`. 3) You need to describe what the original state of the document is to which you're applying the repeating section content control so that we can test/repro the problem. 4) WHICH line of code is triggering the error? `InsertItemAfter` or the line before it?

Comment: Noted re WinForms, I do indeed mean a Repeating Section content control in Word. I have replaced the use of this.Application.ActiveDocument with simply "this" in the code as advised (no apparent change in the result). I would be interested to understand  the risks exposed by using this.Application.ActiveDocument in a VSTO document-level customisation?

Comment: The state of the document in this demo is an unchanged default blank document template. To recreate just create a new Word 2013 and 2016 VSTO Template project in Visual Studio 2017, copy in the code to the ThisDocument partial class (but with your correction to the use of this.Application.Activedocument) and press Start. The rest follows as described.

Comment: The line that triggers the error is the one before InsertItemAfter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can duplicate what you're seeing - I don't know why it's doing this, seems to be almost some kind of race condition because after the document is opened (click "Continue") it works manually...

I found a workaround. It appears that selecting the table puts whatever is causing Word to pick up the content control in the first cell back where it belongs:

```
private void AddTableRepeatingSection()
{
    //Programatically duplicates the table as a repeating section
    Word.Table table = this.Sections[1].Range.Tables[1];
    Word.Range rSRange = table.Range;
    rSRange.Select();
    Word.Range r = this.Application.Selection.Range;
    Word.ContentControl rSCC = this.ContentControls.Add
        (Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRepeatingSection, r);
    rSCC.RepeatingSectionItems[1].InsertItemAfter();
}
```

Comment: Yes adding `rSRange.Select();` seems resolves. Why did you also add the additional statement `Word.Range r = this.Application.Selection.Range;` as `rSRange.Select();` on its own seems sufficient?

Comment: @January59 Only because it feels better to me to have a Range object :-) That, and it made the longer line of code fit better here, on the page. In my original test I used the selection "straight".